# Get member variable via other variable name C#

Tags: c#

I wasn't sure how else to title this question.
I am trying to retrieve member variables of a class via another variable. Let me explain with an example.

This is my code where I am trying to access the value of a member variable in the `Network` class.
(`item` is **NOT** the name of the variable I am trying to access. `item` holds the string of the variable I am trying to access)

```
private void addKeyValuePairRow(string item) {
    addRow(item);
    addKeyLabel(item, false);
    addValueLabel(item);

    if (item.Contains("_"))
        item = item.Replace("_", "");

    setValue(Network[item]);
}
```

**Network** class:

```
public class Network {
    public string DefaultGateway { get; set; }
    public string ExternalIP { get; set; }
    public string SSID { get; set; }
    public string NetworkConnection { get; set; }
    public string NetworkConnectionType { get; set; }
    public string InternetConnection { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

So say I am trying to get `DefaultGateway`, this would be my code calling the method:

```
addKeyValuePairRow("Default_Gateway");
```

I feel like this would be a relatively simple task but cannot find anything on it.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You can use reflection. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue(v=vs.110).aspx for details

Comment: Depending on how much of operations your application will perform the solution of your problem may vary quite widely but one thing is for sure. The use of reflection or some of 3rd party libraries such as `Automapper` is a way to do it.  The Reflection (all these GetType(), GetProperty() etc) works slow and may cause performance issues on a high workload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
var src = new Network();
setValue(src.GetType().GetProperty(item).GetValue(src, null));
```

You've not defined where your Network class is instantiated anywhere in your question however.